# class.getResource() is null though it is in classpath

Tags: java, jar, null, resources, classpath

I have a jar containing the main class of a project. This depends on several other jars that reside in a `lib` directory. One class of such a dependend jar loads a ressource `"/Data/foo/bar/file.txt"`. But loading this file as ressource leads to null.

Here is the directory structure:

```
./main.jar
./lib/lib1.jar
./lib/lib2.jar
./lib/lib3.jar
./lib/runtimedata/Data/foo/bar/file.txt
```

This is the classpath of the manifest.mf of the main.jar:

```
lib/lib1.jar lib/lib2.jar lib/lib3.jar lib/runtimedata
```

I start the application via

```
java -jar main.jar
```

The `lib2.jar` contains a class that tries to load the file with

```
ThatClass.class.getResource("/Data/foo/bar/file.txt");
```

But that happens to be null. Why? lib/runtimedata is in the classpath. 
I even tried to put the `Data` directory into lib/lib/runtimedata, in case the path is relative to the jar file containing the loading class. But that doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:

Running the application with

```
java -cp main.jar:lib/*.jar:lib/runtimedata my.package.Main
```

works correctly.

**EDIT 2**:

I cannot change that lib that does the resource loading. I am only using that lib. The only things I can change is the main.jar the classpath and the command line.

Comment: I always use `X.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt")`. Maybe that helps. Try `ThatClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Data/foo/bar/file.txt");`

Comment: @marioosh No, it doesn't. I am sorry. But I cannot change the used libs. I have to use them as they are. I am only able to set the classpath and the way the application is started.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the path with a "/", it's considered as absolute. Try `ThatClass.class.getResource("/runtime/Data/foo/bar/file.txt");`

Otherwise, if you cant't change the code, put the file on /Data/foo/bar/file.txt

Comment: I didn't think so. A path starting with `"/"` is absolute. That is correct. But it should be absolute to the classpath. Not absolute to the filesystem. Since I have added the `"lib/runtimedata"` to the class path, this should provide the correct root. For example, I didn't put `"/"` or `"."` to the classpath. So putting the Data directory into the root of the filesystem or the directory of the `main.jar` shouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In a development environment, this can sometimes happen when resources have not been processed during the build. Using Gradle and building your main JAR or main test JAR will depend on the compileJava tasks in your libs, but will not trigger their resources to be processed. You can see if this is happening by looking in your build dir to see if resources for your libs have been copied over. If they haven't been copied the resource loader won't find them at runtime.

If this is the problem, a full build will fix the issue and published JARs should always have their resources. But, it's nice to be able to trigger e.g. the test task for an individual module and know that it will always pull in everything it needs. If you have a library with essential resources that must always be present, you can force them to be processed in partial builds by adding this to the build.gradle of the library:

```
    compileJava.dependsOn(processResources)
```